# excel checkboxes to hide and unhide rows disappear when i save and reopen file

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 sheets in excel where if you tick the checkboxes on the first sheet it hides or unhides the rows on sheet2. I used active x controls and set checkbox properties to 'move and size with cells' but when i unhide the rows, the checkboxes disappear but are still in the document as their height changes and remains at 0.(the rows appear just fine). Please help!!

Comment: What happend if you remove the checkbox property 'move and size with cells'?

Comment: I've tried to change it to 'move but don't size with cells' and this still has the same problem. if i don't move and size with cells the checkboxes pile up at the bottom when the rows are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX checkboxes are reknown for problems like these. FOrms checkboxes are a bit better, but I would advise to just use cells with data validation set to list and have it accept 0/1 or True/False. It is relatively easy to set up an event macro that toggles the value of those cells after a double-click for instance.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this on a separate sheet to see if it works better. If i do use form check boxes, is there a way to hide them with the rows and prevent them stacking up on top of one another?

Comment: Both the ActiveX and the forms controls don't always behave well with hiding and displaying rows I'm afraid. Hence my advice to use Data Validation instead.